# Disable browser scrolling with the middle mouse scroll button

Tags: javascript, flash, scroll, mousewheel

I have a flash element on my page that you interact with by using the middle mouse scroll wheel. The page is long. So when scrolling with the mouse wheel it interacts with the Flash element AND scrolls the browser window.

Is there a way to disable browser scrolling while the Flash element is active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.body.style.overflow=allowScroll?"":"hidden";
```

Where allowScroll is a boolean.

Comment: Very simple, I should have thought of it myself. Now I'm being lazy! So to complete the script, when disabling browser scrolling, simply swtich allowScroll = true/false. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
<!-- disables browser mouse scrolling -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',wheel,false);
}

function wheel(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue=false;
}
window.onmousewheel=document.onmousewheel=wheel;
</script>
```

I have "extracted" this function from the Flash MouseWheelTrap which can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/mousewheeltrap/

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted one because it also allows to block scrolling via dragging the middle button.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWFWheel: http://www.libspark.org/wiki/SWFWheel/en