# Firefox - Text Scrollable in HTML Text Input

Tags: html, css, firefox, input

Here's a jsFiddle with my situation demoed: http://jsfiddle.net/SFrbZ/4/

Basically, I want to have input fields in table cells and have the inputs set to a fixed height and font-size. What's happening now is that users are able to hover over or click on the input and using the mouse wheel can scroll the text up and partially out of frame. Highlighting the text also allows you to move it up. The following code shows the barebones of this issue as well:

HTML:

```
<input class="scroll" type="text" value="1"></input>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll {
display: table-cell;
width: 38px;
height: 8px;
font-size: 11px;
color: Black;
font-family: Calibri;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(182, 231, 201);
}
```

Oddly enough, this is only occuring on Firefox and not Chrome, IE, or Safari. As you can see in the jsFiddle, increasing the height of the field (or lowering the font-size) solves the problem, but this is not a viable solution for me.

I've tried a number of alterations in an attempt to fix it but have come up dry. Messing with overflow, line-height, padding, margins, display type, etc. and nothing seemed to do the trick. Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to install a Javascript handler for scroll events, on elements of class `.scroll`, which simply swallows the event and returns false -- this will prevent the element from being scrolled by any means, which should solve the problem as stated. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFrbZ/6/), using jQuery, demonstrates the solution, and the meat of it is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scroll').scroll(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Without jQuery, the solution is still feasible by means of `window.addEventListener` &c., but jQuery makes it so much simpler that, if you're not already using that library in your project, I'd recommend adding it just for this purpose.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work in the fiddle, were you able to resolve the issue using this code?

Comment: I'd thought I was, but evidently I wasn't watching what I did with my mouse pointer, such that my scroll events weren't hitting the right element. However, trying the method described [in this SO question's accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554030/disable-browser-scrolling-with-the-middle-mouse-scroll-button) worked, as can be seen [in this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFrbZ/8/).

Comment: Looks like that does it, though I'd like to keep mouse scroll functionality for the rest of the page so that when the table is large users are able to scroll with the mouse wheel. However, this helps quite a bit and should help me reach a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to change the line-height property of the .scroll css class to match the height.  Using you're example:

```
.scroll {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 38px;
  height: 8px;

  line-height: 8px;

  font-size: 11px;
  color: Black;
  font-family: Calibri;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(182, 231, 201);
}
```

The issue is that the text technically doesn't fit in that box.  Text with a height of 11px usually has a couple of pixels on top and bottom as 'padding' to make it so that multi-line text has spacing between the lines.  As a result, it appears the text fits, but it doesn't actually.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that fix to no avail. Line-height does not appear to have any effect on the boxes.