# Google maps; add place card to marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As you can see on the following image, the `div` (top left) shows the current marker address/directions/ save..

[image]

This was done using the embedded `iframe` code from google maps. But how can you do the same with custom "coded" map?

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({
    "address": nw.google_pointer
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: parseInt(nw.google_zoom),
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: nw.google_pointer
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Comment: take a look at [custom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Comment: hi, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [jsbin with my solution](http://jsbin.com/yiwaco/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

**Background:**

I needed a better solution to the mouse wheel scroll problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768772/prevent-a-google-maps-iframe-from-capturing-the-mouses-scrolling-wheel-behavior) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763672/custom-google-map-add-place-card). The best way to get the behaviour I wanted was to stick with the API, but I really like the card shown in the embedded version.

**Method:**

1. Copied card code and associated css from embedded version.
2. In javascript, append card html into the rendered map when it's ready

**My Customizations:**

1. Took off the "Save" option because it doesn't work.
2. Positioned card on the top right - look at the html that is appended in javascript, it's hardcoded with absolute position, you can change this or associate it with a class if you prefer.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: If you use `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce`, place card will be added just once. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I added second map in @jcsmesquita answer but there are same place cards on two maps : `http://jsbin.com/vixehodaka/edit?html,css,js,output`

so I changed javascript code a bit : `jsbin.com/dezorezohe/edit?html,css,js,output`