# Using the Google Maps JavaScript API to add a 'place-card' to an embedded map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Does anyone know how to enable the 'place-card' on an embedded Google Map using the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)?

When I use the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) a 'place-card' will be present in the top left corner of the map. This 'place-card' includes the address, a 'Directions' link, and a 'View larger map' link.

I would prefer to use the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) to embed my map but when I create a map using this API the place-card is missing and the 'view larger map' link is replaced with a subtle Google logo in the bottom left corner.

I have scoured the Google Docs and I just can't seem to figure out a way to enable this place-card. Is this possible or do I have to revert back to using the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)?

I figure making a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) to replicate the 'place-card' would be a waste of my time.

Comment: making a custom control to replicate the 'place-card' is what you need to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps; add place card to marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346076/google-maps-add-place-card-to-marker)