# Display place information with Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently use Google maps embeds to display places information like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode

The big problem with embeds is the scrollwheel and mobile touch drag. Therefore, I'm converting it to the Javascript API where you can set options to take care of those issues. However, I need to know how to display places information as per the default google map style (I don't want to create my own custom infowindow and all).

How can I use the default places information display from google maps?

Comment: You can't, you have to code it yourself.  All the information needed to create it is available via various services in the API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the Google Maps JavaScript API to add a 'place-card' to an embedded map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264122/using-the-google-maps-javascript-api-to-add-a-place-card-to-an-embedded-map) (but no answer there)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying address box in Google Maps Javascript API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565226/displaying-address-box-in-google-maps-javascript-api) (no answer there either)