# How can move Place card in Google Maps Embed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Google Maps in my webpage.

How can move place card in Google Maps embed?
For example: move place card top 200px, or right aligned place card or bottom aligned place card, please I need help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346076/google-maps-add-place-card-to-marker

Comment: Thanks, Morpheus